# Path to vim and sudo executables

Tags: linux, vim, path, sudo, centos7

I've messed up my PATH variable by editing /etc/environment, I don't have rm, sudo or many commands. Can someone tell me the path to the vim and sudo executables so I can fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path to `vim` can possibly vary, for `vi` it's `/usr/bin/vi`.

You can still fix your `PATH` by exporting it manually in shell as below:

- Ubuntu default:

  ```
  export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
  ```
- CentOS default (tested on VM):

  ```
  export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin
  ```

You can also look for the binaries by the following commands (if you run `sudo updatedb` before):

```
locate vim | grep -w "vim$"
```

or:

```
type -a vim
```

The best would be to fix your `PATH` by adding the right values into the right *rc* file. Normally you set that in `~/.profile` for the current user, or adding new as part of `/etc/init.d` scripts:

```
$ grep -R PATH /etc/init.d
/etc/init.d/functions:PATH="/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin"
/etc/init.d/functions:export PATH
/etc/init.d/netconsole:PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:$PATH
/etc/init.d/vboxadd:PATH=$PATH:/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
/etc/init.d/vboxadd-service:PATH=$PATH:/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
/etc/init.d/vboxadd-x11:PATH=$PATH:/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
```

Answer (score 1):

Vim:

```
$ which vim
/usr/bin/vim
```

sudo:

```
$ which sudo
/usr/bin/sudo
```